# I am looking for a source each of ActiveRecord. What is to_a?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

[rails/delegation.rb at v4.2.4 · rails/rails](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v4.2.4/activerecord/lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb#L46)

```
delegate :to_xml, :to_yaml, :length, :collect, :map, :each, :all?, :include?, :to_ary, :join, to: :to_a
```

## Breakpoint this line

```
to_a
=> undefined local variable or method `to_a' for ActiveRecord::Delegation:Module
```

The breakpoint stop immediately after the rails start.

---

## delegate method document(comment) say

[rails/delegation.rb at 7b92798d2fee012bf683c513fb3864a9143a6f71 · rails/rails](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/7b92798d2fee012bf683c513fb3864a9143a6f71/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/module/delegation.rb#L56)

> # Methods can be delegated to instance variables, class variables, or constants
>    # by providing them as a symbols:

`delegate` run `module_eval(method_def, file, line)`

[rails/delegation.rb at 7b92798d2fee012bf683c513fb3864a9143a6f71 · rails/rails](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/7b92798d2fee012bf683c513fb3864a9143a6f71/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/module/delegation.rb#L215)

```
module_eval(method_def, file, line)
```

## Breakpoint this line

```
method_def
=> "def each(*args, &block); _ = to_a;  _.each(*args, &block);rescue NoMethodError => e;  if _.nil? && e.name == :each;    raise DelegationError, \"ActiveRecord::Delegation#each delegated to to_a.each, but to_a is nil: \#{self.inspect}\";  else;    raise;  end;end"
```

What is `to_a`?

Comment: What is your question exactly?

Comment: to_a => undefined ... but Ruby can to_a is in Enumerable?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please don't use arbitrary bold text. It's as bad as typing in all upper-case. `to_a` is a basic building block for objects and is inherited from Enumerable. Perhaps you need to read through the documentation for the various core classes? Also, your title, being a question, is supposed to be the first line of your question also. "[ask]"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank to @Bryan Oemar.(https://stackoverflow.com/a/33510586/1979953)
I found `to_a` in rails.
**I need stop the breakpoint after action controller.**

```
to_a.class
=> Array
```

---

```
self.method(:to_a).source_location
=> ["/Users/shingonakanishi/Documents/raku/selforderweb/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.4/lib/active_record/relation.rb", 242]
```

### `to_a` method in rails/relation.rb

[rails/relation.rb at d2315d0c3b1ede89b7cce6a77c647285359243c5 · rails/rails](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/d2315d0c3b1ede89b7cce6a77c647285359243c5/activerecord/lib/active_record/relation.rb#L250)

```
# Converts relation objects to Array.
def to_a
  load
  @records
end
```

Answer (score 1):

> What is to_a?

This is a method that will return an array, if the method is implemented. 
See for example: http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-to_a

If you get an undefined, that means the method is not implemented (aka undefined) for the object your calling the method on.

What is the object you are calling to_a on? This object will not have the to_a method.

Comment: Runtime include to_a of Enumerable after delegate? 
I wonder where?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish here? 
When and on what object are you trying to call this to_a method?

Comment: oh I see. I run rails start, so to_a is undef. but My Controller `to_a.class => Array`

Comment: In answers we shouldn't say things like "What is the object you are calling to_a on?" That's inviting the OP to join into a conversation, but answers are statements, not conversations. A comment to the original question would be more appropriate for that.